# Has interpretation of android:label changed in Android Nougat (7)?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have added `applicationIdSuffix` in on every build type in gradle, to be able have every build type installed at the same device at the same time. I also have different string resources for every build type, which means I can have a string resource `"app_name"` unique for every build type (e.g. My App, My App (beta), My App (debug)). I use the `android:label="app_name"` on `<application>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`, `android:label="app_title"` on `<activity>` and `android:label="app_name"` on `<intent-filter>` element, which gave me a perfect setup: in launcher, every build type got its unique launcher name but the title in the Toolbar was the same (no unique resource for `app_title`).

But running the same app with multiple build types on Android Nougat phones (and emulators) gives med the same launcher names. I'm able to have the installed at the same time, but the app launcher title is the same... Any idea how to solve this on Nougat devices? It works on Marshmallow and below.

**Update 1:**
Can't get it to work. Let me share some code:

```
<application
        ...
        android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <a... android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <i...
                android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </i...>
        </a...>
</app...>
```

/debug/res/values/strings.xml contains launcher_name="My app -D"
But launcher label is My app when running in AS on emu.

**Update 2:**
Filed a bug at Android.com. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223706

BR,
J

Comment: How are you defining the String resources? Are you using a Gradle expression for adding a resource on each build type or do you have one string resource file in each build type source folder?

Comment: @ErikHellman I have one string resource in each build type res folder. But I did try to set the string res per build type in build.gradle but it didn't change anyting... Should it?

Comment: Yeah, seems strange. The only thing that has changed here is that Android 7.0 has more advanced type of localization support. Basically, if you would have a default name somewhere and a localized version, and you would expect the localized version to be loaded, then things could be different.

Are all the string files in the different build types placed in the default values folder (e.g., src/debug/res/values/strings.xml, src/release/res/values/strings.xml etc.)?

Comment: Yes, they are: beta/res/values/string.xml, debug/res/values/strings.xml, main/res/values/strings.xml... And in the build/intermediates/res/merged/beta/values/values.xml for example, app_name is my beta app name, which is correct... I've noticed how some other installed apps launcher names has changed since updating to Nougat, so probably it's not my setup specifically that is wrong... @ErikHellman

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just tested this myself and can't reproduce the problem. My advice is that you check how your resource strings are placed. If you want the app name to differ for each build type, make sure you have that resource placed in each different build and not in the `main/res/` folder.

I created a labels.xml where added `<string name="app_name">My App (X)</string>` where X is `release`, `debug` or `beta` depending on the build type. That works on all Android versions I've been able to test on.

Just make sure you don't have the string resource in the main folder as well. Although, that should result in build error due to duplicate resources.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Let me share some code:
<app...
        ...
        android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <a... android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <i...
                android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </i...>
        </a...>
</app...>
/debug/res/values/strings.xml contains launcher_name="My app -D"
But launcher label is My app when running in AS on emu.

Comment: Try and see if you can reproduce it in a new clean project and post a bug about it at b.android.com (post a link to the issue here and I can follow it as well).

Comment: I reproduced in a clean project with same output. Filed a bug at Android.com. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223706
Thanks for your efforts Erik!